# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error Showing

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i+=3) {
        System.out.print("Enter Exam Mark:");
        Marks[i] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Coursework Mark:");
        Marks[i+1] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Weighting:");
        Marks[i+2] = input.nextInt();

    }


public double[] computemarks(int[] Marks) {

    double[] marks = new double[6];
    double computedmark;

    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x+=3) {

        if (Marks[x] >= 35 && Marks[x+1] >= 35) {

            computedmark = ((Marks[x+1] * Marks[x+2]) + (Marks[x] * (100.0 - Marks[x+2]))) / 100.0;

        } else {

            computedmark = Math.min(Marks[x], Marks[x+1]);

        }

        marks[x] = computedmark;

    }
    return marks;

}
```

Why is "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" showing during runtime?
I've played around with the for loops but it's still not working.

FYI, The Marks array has 18 available slots in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your `marks` array has a size 6 in the `computemarks` method, but you are setting it's with x index, here:

```
marks[x] = computedmark;
```

which is taken out of the loop and after the 3rd iteration is equals to 9 yet.

**update** according to your comment, it could be made like:

```
int idx = 0; //here is additional index declared
for(int x=0; x < 15; x+=3) {

    if (Marks[x] >= 35 && Marks[x+1] >= 35) {

        computedmark = ((Marks[x+1] * Marks[x+2]) + (Marks[x] * (100.0 - Marks[x+2]))) / 100.0;

    } else {

        computedmark = Math.min(Marks[x], Marks[x+1]);

    }

    marks[idx++] = computedmark; //here is additional index is used with post incrementing

}
return marks;
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. Is there a way to fix this without setting marks to 18 slots?

Comment: Yes, just make an additional index, which will be multiplied out of the loop

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Could you provide me with an example please?

Comment: @MartinRand updated an answer, use an index which will be increased by 1 on every iteration

Comment: Thanks for that! The error is no longer appearing, however, the 6th value of marks is showing as 0...

Comment: @MartinRand you make just 5 iterations, because of the x<15, but it has to be x<=15 or just x<16. take a look, during the 6th iteration, x is equals to 15 and ignored